# Understanding AWS Cognito usage in iOS apps

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ejabberd, amazon-cognito

My backend app server (ejabberd, hosted on AWS EC2) has its own user authentication process. My iOS client connects with it directly for user login but the client also needs to access S3 buckets separately - for which I'm trying to leverage AWS Cognito.

I could have the app upload / download data to / from S3 buckets if I incorporate the below recommended iOS SDK code in my app. Documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html) ...

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"IDENTITY_POOL_ID"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]
initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

However, my question is - where / how are the credentials being refreshed every one hour? The above code does not seem to be sufficient to me - the identity pool is actually hard-coded in the app and can be retrieved by someone decompiling it. Am probably missing out something basic here...

Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity pool id is normally embedded in the app, you're not missing a step on that front. The risk can be alleviated by using your auth and unauth roles to tightly define what each user and type of user is allowed to do.

The credentials provider automatically manages credentials for you. When they're expired, it will get new ones and use those. All you have to do is pass it on to whatever AWS client your app needs at the time.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Bailey. So does that mean that I need to implement the fetching of the identity ID from AWS in my app server, and I then pass that back to my mobile client, which uses that to connect to S3? I might be mistaken here again in my understanding - I was earlier assuming that my server would have no role to play and only the iOS client needs to incorporate the credentials...

Comment: That's only a part of the flow if you're using developer authenticated identities. If not, the SDK does that for you as well.

Comment: Aah yes I am ... as I was alluding to, my app server is responsible for user authentication, so I have my own app-specific username, etc. Sorry one more question - is this the right blog for me to follow / implement the flow I mentioned. I ask because I couldn't locate BFTask and read somewhere that its been deprecated...? Thanks again!   http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities

Comment: With dev auth, the client should still handle 95% of getting the ID. The call to the server to log in will return it, at which point it'll continue as normal

Comment: Thanks much once again @Jeff Bailey ... much appreciated your help! I'll give this a try and get back in case something doesn't click.. thanks again!